# delete rows based on

Tags: excel, vba

I am a little bit stacked. I am trying to compare column A if they are duplicates and delete all rows, leaving just the last revision, last Version row for every document.
I have Column A - Document Name, Column B - Revision (A,B,C..), Column C - Version (1,2,3..). As an example: (A2= Rev A Version 2) Document "x" I have in row 1 as A1, Row 2 as A2, Row 3 as C2, Row 4 as D1, Row 5 as D2. I need something to delete all rows 1-4 and leave just row 5 which is the last revision and last version (Rev D Version 2). For Document "Y' need to remain just the row with Rev D, Version 2, and so on.

```
Document Name   Revision    Version  Title
x               A           1        BAY CONTROLLER BLOCK LOGIC DIAGRAM
x               A           2        BAY CONTROLLER BLOCK LOGIC DIAGRAM
x               C           2        BAY CONTROLLER BLOCK LOGIC DIAGRAM
x               D           1        BAY CONTROLLER BLOCK LOGIC DIAGRAM
x               D           2        BAY CONTROLLER BLOCK LOGIC DIAGRAM
y               C           1        BAY CONTROLLER BLOCK LOGIC DIAGRAM
y               C           2        BAY CONTROLLER BLOCK LOGIC DIAGRAM
y               C           3        BAY CONTROLLER BLOCK LOGIC DIAGRAM
y               D           1        BAY CONTROLLER BLOCK LOGIC DIAGRAM
y               D           2        BAY CONTROLLER BLOCK LOGIC DIAGRAM*
```

Comment: Hi Diana, welcome to Stackoverflow. 
Since tables do not show well, can you take a screenshot of the example table you are talking about?

Comment: If you are not familiar with VBA, I would suggest creating an additional column with a formula stating 1 for duplicates. You can use the COUNTIFS formula to check if a row exists wherein all values are the same. Afterwards, you can set a filter and show only the rows with value 1 and delete them all at once.

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), take the [SO Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That said see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution that will remove duplicate rows based on Column A

```
Sub test()
Sheet1.Cells.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to be clear when you ask a question. Your statement `"I am trying to compare column A if they are duplicates and delete the whole row"` you failed to explain comparing the additional columns you wrote in your comment above. Please edit your question with a complete narrative and example of what your are trying to accomplish, to include code you have tried to accomplish your task.

Comment: Diana, sorry your question in this post is unclear and confusing, using the comments section to clarify your question is improper, you need to edit your post. Please read the SO help files i suggested in my initial comment.